# HTML5 Videos not working when more than 1 on a page

Tags: html5-video

Wondering if the ID has to match the name of the video OR not be in there at all, but having problem getting videos to work on pages that contain more than 1 video. 1 works not problem, 3, does not..here is the link http://www.clarkekoi.com/video-blog.html....a solution greatly appreciated...thanks. Randall

Comment: working in chrome for multiple videos, but not firefox...using mp4 and webm..makes no sense if a single video works in FF but not multiple ?

Answer (score 0):

i would check your webM files again. is the source right in your brwoser, and do the videos work (just click 'n drop them from your hard drive in your firefox). your code is working as you can see in chrome and safari, which take the mp4 source, so i m quite sure the webM videofiles are broken?!